# read json from file upload php

Tags: php

I have a php page where it should be able to upload `.json` files and my PHP code needs to read the json from the file that is imported.

I tried this:
HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="importfile" id="inportfile" onchange="this.form.submit()" accept="application/json" style="display:none"/> 
    <button id="import">Import</button>
    <script>
    $('#import').click(function(){ $('#inportfile').trigger('click'); });
    </script>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['importfile'])){
   // read json file
   $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['importfile']['tmp_name']);
   $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Anyone know how to do this in a proper way that works?

Comment: There's [documentation on Handling File Uploads](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: There is no json handling in this documentation

Comment: There is no problem with json in your code either

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: alright added the `enctype` attibute what now?

Comment: *"what now"* well, does the upload work now?

Comment: I'm not "uploading", i'm just reading the contents of the (json) file

Comment: "importing" means nothing in this context. You are uploading. Even if the webserver is on your machine you're submitting a file via a form. Anyone will tell you that yes, you're uploading a file.

Comment: Ok but after my "upload" im not saving the file, im just reading the contents and that doesn't work

Comment: Ok, what doesn't work? It's not in the session? It's not uploaded? Please be a bit more precise with your question.

Comment: Is what I'm doing right?

Comment: Depends on what you expect to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need yo add a new tag in the form `enctype` :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```